# Classes and Ids do not work in Style Tags

Tags: html, css, class, styles

For some reason if I try to style elements using classes or ids in Style tags then nothing happens. It works fine if the CSS selector is just looking for a tag and no class or id. It also works fine in an external style sheet. I have tested this in both Chrome and Firefox and unless this is some rule that I have never heard of, then I have no idea what is going on.
Something as simple as this does not even work. The p is coloured blue however the h1.1 does not become red.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
h1.1 {color:red;}
p {color:blue;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<h1 class="1">This is a heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Could someone please explain why this is happening? How can style an element using its class in style tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class names must begin with a letter.

Comment: I thought I was still having the same problem with another page, but I realised that I somehow slipped a period before the class name.

Answer (score 2):

That is because you have used `1` as class name – and `.1` does not make a valid CSS selector, so it would have to be escaped: http://jsfiddle.net/wJsbj/

See also:

- [CSS character escape sequences](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes)
- [SO: What characters are valid in CSS class selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-selectors)

Answer (score 2):

check css class name conventions `css name conventions`

A css class name should be started with alphabet A-Z or a-z .

Answer (score 1):

Class or id name should start with an alphabet.

Answer (score 1):

You can't start the name of class with a number. 
Try this:[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/BlackSRC/NBJCT/)

```
<html>
<head>
   <style type="text/css">
      h1.a1 {color:red;}
      p {color:blue;}
   </style>
</head>
<body>
   <h1 class="a1">This is a heading</h1>
   <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need the h1 as well. Just write:  .a1 {color:red;}  With the dot, you are defining a class which you apply in the html to any element you like by including class="a1" in any tag. That's the beauty of classes...you can use them as much as you like providing the html tag you're applying it to makes sense.